# FullPage JS - Fixed background image for specific sections?

Tags: css, fullpage.js

I am using [FullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for a website. For my 2-4 sections I would like to have the background image remain fixed so that only the content within the section is scrolling and not the background image. Here's what I've tried:

```css
#section1 {
  background:#ccc;
}
#section2, #section3, #section4 {
  background:url('http://placehold.it/1024x768/7777c1/fff') no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
#section5 {
  background:#000;
}
  #section5 h1 {
    color:#fff;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.3/fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.3/fullpage.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section" id="section1">
     <div class="slide"><h1>Simple Demo</h1></div>
     <div class="slide"><h1>Only text</h1></div>
     <div class="slide"><h1>And text</h1></div>
     <div class="slide"><h1>And more text</h1></div>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section2"><h1>No wraps, no extra markup</h1></div>
 <div class="section" id="section3"><h1>Just the simplest demo ever</h1></div>
  <div class="section" id="section4"><h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1></div>
  <div class="section" id="section5"><h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'OPEN-SOURCE-GPLV3-LICENSE'
 });
</script>
```

I was hoping `background-attachment:fixed;` would do the trick, but the background still scrolls with the section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap everything in a wrapper div and place the background image on that.

Any sections can have an rgba background-color, a fully opaque background color, or be transparent by default depending on how you want each section to appear..

If you need to change the background image, you have some callbacks you can hook into. `afterLoad` & `onLeave`. In here you can get the current section (`this.anchor`) and even the `direction`.

One you know that information, you can change the `backgroundImage` of the `.wrapper` quite easily.

```js
var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'OPEN-SOURCE-GPLV3-LICENSE',
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5'],
  onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction) {
    if (this.anchor === 'page2' && direction === 'down') {
      document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.backgroundImage = `url(https://placekitten.com/700/350)`
    } else if (this.anchor === 'page2' && direction === 'up') {
      document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.backgroundImage = `url(https://placekitten.com/600/300)`
    }

  }
});
```

```css
#section1 {
  background: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.5);
}

#section2 {
  background: white;
}

#section2 {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#section5 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper {
  background: url('https://placekitten.com/600/300') no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.3/fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.3/fullpage.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="slide">
        <h1>Simple Demo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h1>Only text</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h1>And text</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h1>And more text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
      <h1>No wraps, no extra markup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
      <h1>Just the simplest demo ever</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section4">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section5">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, unfortunately I forgot to mention that there will be more sections that will have a different fixed background image, any idea how to account for that? IE Section 1 will have a solid background color, 2-4 will have a fixed background image, 5 will have a solid background color and then 6-8 will have a different fixed background image from 2-4.

Comment: Updated with a bit of JS to change the background image depending on which section you have just left.

Comment: The onLeave function doesn't seem to work in Vue. Tried fiddling around but still getting bunch of errors with it.

Comment: Sorry, this question was not about Vue. Perhaps you could ask a new question and drop a link here.